# Move all repos that are under one organization into my own github account

Tags: github

I have github org https://github.com/Cosi-12b which I created in a bout of over enthusiasm about organizations. It contains a bunch (n) repos.

Is there a simple (i.e not O(n) step) process to move all the repos, in one fell swoop to my personal GitHub account https://github.com/pitosalas?

Answer (score 1):

[Transferring a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository) is no trivial task and involve a confirmation step, for the new owner to accept.

That is why [Converting an organization into a user](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/converting-an-organization-into-a-user) involve a step where you transfer each organization repository to the new user account. O(n)

You might consider scripting those transfers, using a script like [`jdbean/github-api-bulk-transfer`](https://github.com/jdbean/github-api-bulk-transfer).